# How to create dictionary from a listinfo?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am filtering a list of data havong this pattern:

```
('timestamp', 'node_source', 'node_destination', 'node_source_counter_acces_to_specific_function')
```

I am trying to extract and display data per node_source'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_info= [('1547977394', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '1'),
('1547977395', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '2'), 
('1547977396', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '3'), 
('1547977397', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000700000000000000', '4'), 
('1547977398', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '5'), 
('1547977399', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '6'), 
('1547977400', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '7'),
('1547977401', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '8'),
('1547977402', '02141592cc0000000200000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '9'),
('1547977403', '02141592cc0000000100000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '10'),
('1547977404', '02141592cc0000000200000000000000', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '11'),
('1547977405', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '12'),
('1547977406', '02141592cc0000000300000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '13'),
('1547977407', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '14'),
('1547977408', '02141592cc0000000400000000000000', '02141592cc0000000500000000000000', '15')]

#print(list_info)
for  i, item in enumerate(list_info):
    print(item[1])

dict_node = {}
for timestamp, id_src_node, id_dest_node, Counter in list_info:
        dict_node[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp))
        dict_node[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(Counter))
        dict_node[id_dest_node]["dest"].append(id_dest_node)

print(dict_node)
```

But, I have this error I am able to display source node 's information:

```
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
    dict_node[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp))
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
02141592cc0000000100000000000000
02141592cc0000000500000000000000
KeyError: '02141592cc0000000100000000000000'
```

For example, the expected data that must be visuliazed to `node_source:02141592cc0000000100000000000000`  is:

```
('02141592cc0000000100000000000000',timestam':[1547977395,1547977396,1547977397,1547977398,1547977399],'Counter':[2,3,4,5,6],'dest':[02141592cc0000000300000000000000,02141592cc0000000500000000000000,02141592cc0000000700000000000000,02141592cc0000000300000000000000,02141592cc0000000500000000000000])
```

Comment: You need to create the sub dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries don't automatically create values if they don't exist.

Your first line of code modifying the dictionary:

```
dict_node[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp))
```

This is saying: get the dictionary for `id_src_node` and from that dictionary get the `list` for `'timestamp'` and then append a number to that list.

However, no dictionary for `id_src_node` has ever been added to `dict_node`, and certainly no list has been set for key `timestamp` in the non-existent dictionary.

There are a couple of ways of doing this though. There is [**`dict.setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which I don't like the name or syntax, or you can create a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The `defaultdict` will create a particular type of object for a key if the key doesn't already exist.

The outer dictionary needs a dictionary as a default, and that inner dictionary needs a list as a default:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def inner_dict():
    return defaultdict(list)

dict_node = defaultdict(inner_dict)
```

Then, when you access a new key, `dict_node` will add an `inner_dict` which, when you access the inner key, will create an empty list, which you can happily append to:

```
>>> dict_node['02141592cc0000000100000000000000']['timestamp'].append(1234.5)
```

If you try printing the default dictionaries they won't be as neat as a plain `dict`.

To instead use the plain `dict` with `dict.setdefault`:

```
dict_node.setdefault(id_src_node, {}).setdefault("timestamp", []).append(float(timestamp))
```

As you can see it's pretty ugly, but you'll have the `dict` you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am not sure that I am not sure that I understand the solution very well  since I don't have the expected result. For example I have this result for the source node 1: 
# '02141592cc0000000100000000000000': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'timestamp': [1547977394.0, 1547977395.0, 1547977396.0, 1547977397.0, 1547977398.0, 1547977399.0, 1547977403.0], 'Counter': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]}), #   Could you please give me more explanation.

Comment: What was the expected result? Why do you need to print `dict_node`? It may be better to post a new question and improve it using edits, rather than discuss in comments.